# Difference between Cypher Queries. (neo4j movie db)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am doing the exercises found in the `:play intro-neo4j-exercises` (exercise 4.10).
Everything seems good, but I cannot understand exactly the difference between the two queries. Can someone please elaborate?

```
MATCH path =  (p:Person)-[:PRODUCED]->(m:Movie) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( (p)-[:DIRECTED]->(:Movie) )
RETURN p.name, m.title
```

Returns:

```
|"a.name"      │"m.title"               │
╞══════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│"Joel Silver" │"The Matrix"            │
├──────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver" │"The Matrix Reloaded"   │
├──────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver" │"The Matrix Revolutions"│
├──────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Stefan Arndt"│"Cloud Atlas"           │
├──────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver" │"V for Vendetta"        │
├──────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver" │"Speed Racer"           │
├──────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver" │"Ninja Assassin"        │
└──────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

WHILE:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:PRODUCED]->(m:Movie)
WHERE NOT EXISTS( (p)-[:DIRECTED]->(m) )
RETURN p.name, m.title
```

RETURNS:

```
╒═════════════════╤════════════════════════╕
│"a.name"         │"m.title"               │
╞═════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│"Joel Silver"    │"The Matrix"            │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver"    │"The Matrix Reloaded"   │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver"    │"The Matrix Revolutions"│
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Nora Ephron"    │"When Harry Met Sally"  │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Stefan Arndt"   │"Cloud Atlas"           │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Lana Wachowski" │"V for Vendetta"        │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Lilly Wachowski"│"V for Vendetta"        │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver"    │"V for Vendetta"        │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver"    │"Speed Racer"           │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Lana Wachowski" │"Ninja Assassin"        │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Joel Silver"    │"Ninja Assassin"        │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│"Lilly Wachowski"│"Ninja Assassin"        │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query finds `Person`s who `PRODUCED` the `Movie m`, but did not direct **any** movie. The second query finds `Person`s who `PRODUCED` the `Movie m` but did not direct that **particular** `Movie m`. You know this because in the second query, the bound variable `m` is used in the `WHERE` clause, whereas in the first query, only the label `:Movie` is used in the `WHERE` clause.

Incidentally, the `path =` part of the first query does nothing.